# Unity3d EventTrigger - on pointer enter image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using `eventTrigger` to trigger the event when pointer enter an image. Basically, I have an `image` within the `canvas`. At the `image` I added `EventTrigger` component, add event type `Pointer Enter`, then link to a function of my script:

```
public void PointerEnter(){
    Debug.Log ("pointer enter");
}
```

This works fine. But what if I want to pass some data to the script? For example, the name of the `image`. In normal `Unity3d` `raycast` scenario, we can do this:

```
if (Physics.Raycast (ray0, out hit)) {
                Debug.Log (hit.collider.gameObject.name);//<-- get the name
            }
```

But how to do that if we use `EventTrigger`?

Comment: have you tried something like  EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name

Comment: `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name` get `Null Reference`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `IPointerEnterHandler` then override the `OnPointerEnter()` function which provides `PointerEventData`data as parameter. Get the name of the GameObject from that information.

Attach the **simple** `MouseEnterScript` script to your `Canvas` and it should detect all mouse enter on any UI.

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MouseEnterScript: MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Name: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);
        Debug.Log("Tag: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.tag);
        Debug.Log("GameObject: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but I have 4 images put side by side, then it only work on the first entered image but did not call `OnPointerEnter` again until I exit from all the images, then reenter again.

Comment: I do not understand your current problem. As long as the images are different GameObjects, that should detect mouse enter on each GameObject/Iimage. For your information, `OnPointerEnter` is only called once when on each image. If you move it to the next Image `OnPointerEnter` will be called again but once. It won't be repeatedly called. You can set a value to true the first time it is called then get the name of the Image clicked. When release, set the value to false. http://pastebin.com/CrZLQmTK